# VueJS 2 debounce on multiple components

Tags: vue.js, quasar, debouncing

I have a Vue component that uses multiple sub-components on it. And on those sub-components I have a watcher that watches for data changes and processes those changes. I would like to implement debounce for this.

```
    watch: {
    data: {
      handler: function () {
        this.processData()
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    processData: debounce(function () {
      console.log(this.id)
    }, 250),
```

The problem is that debounce works so it executes only on the last sub-component.

I have found a solution for debounce function that accepts an additional id [debounceWithId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104199/debounce-function-calls-by-their-arguments)

However there problem is that if I specify this function as follows:

```
  methods: {
    processData: debounceWithId(function () {
      console.log(this.id)
    }, 250, this.id),
```

the last this.id is undefined.

What would be a correct way of using debounce in multiple components so the function fires separately on each component?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First let me add an example that replicates the issue you are describing.

```js
console.clear()

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        console.log("Called from component ", this._uid)
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

Vue.component("doesntwork",{
  props:["value"],
  template:`<div>Component #{{_uid}} Value: {{innerValue}}</div>`,
  data(){
    return {
      innerValue: this.value
    }
  },
  watch:{
    value(newVal){
      this.processData(newVal)
    }
  },
  methods:{
    processData: debounce(function(newVal){
      this.innerValue = newVal
    }, 1000)
  },
})


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    parentValue: null,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  Type some text. Wait one second. Only the *last* component is updated.<br>
  <input type="text" v-model="parentValue">
  <doesntwork :value="parentValue"></doesntwork>
  <doesntwork :value="parentValue"></doesntwork>
  <doesntwork :value="parentValue"></doesntwork>
</div>
```

Essentially what is going on here is that the debounced function is created when the component is compiled, and each instance of the component shares the *same* debounced function. The context of `this` will be different in each one, but it is the same function. I added a `console.log` in the generated debounced function so that you can see that all three components are sharing the same function. That being the case, the function is doing what it is designed to do; it executes *once* after the elapsed period of time, which is why only the last component is updated.

To get around that behavior you need a *unique* debounce function for each component. Here are two ways you can do that.

**Method One**

You can initialize your processData method with what amounts to a placeholder.

```
methods: {
  processData(){}
}
```

Then, in the created lifecycle event, change the processData method to the debounced method.

```
created(){
  this.processData = debounce(function(){
    console.log(this.id)
  }, 250)
}
```

This will give each component a unique debounced function and should take care of the issue where only the *last* component works properly.

Here is an example modified from the above example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("works",{
  props:["value"],
  template:`<div>Component #{{_uid}} Value: {{innerValue}}</div>`,
  data(){
    return {
      innerValue: this.value,
    }
  },
  watch:{
    value(newVal){
      this.processData(newVal)
    }
  },
  methods:{
    processData() {}
  },
  created(){
    this.processData = _.debounce(function(newVal){
      this.innerValue = newVal
    }, 1000)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    parentValue: null,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  Type some text. Wait one second. <em>All</em> components are updated.<br>
  <input type="text" v-model="parentValue">
  <works :value="parentValue"></works>
  <works :value="parentValue"></works>
  <works :value="parentValue"></works>
</div>
```

**Method Two**

Thanks to @RoyJ for suggesting this. You can define the `processData` method in `data`. Typically you do not do this because you don't often *want* multiple copies of a function, and that's why the `methods` section of a component definition exists, but in a case, like this where you *need* a unique function for each component, you can define the method in the data function because the data function is called for *every* instance of the component.

```
data(){
  return {
    innerValue: this.value,
    processData: _.debounce(function(newVal){
      this.innerValue = newVal
    }, 1000)
  }
},
```

Here is an example using that approach.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("works",{
  props:["value"],
  template:`<div>Component #{{_uid}} Value: {{innerValue}}</div>`,
  data(){
    return {
      innerValue: this.value,
      processData: _.debounce(function(newVal){
        this.innerValue = newVal
      }, 1000)
    }
  },
  watch:{
    value(newVal){
      this.processData(newVal)
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    parentValue: null,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  Type some text. Wait one second. <em>All</em> components are updated.<br>
  <input type="text" v-model="parentValue">
  <works :value="parentValue"></works>
  <works :value="parentValue"></works>
  <works :value="parentValue"></works>
</div>
```

Comment: @RoyJ What's your thought? In the codepen I'm not really returning a value, just updating a data property. In the non-working component, the debounced method only ever even fires once. Which...gives me a bit of an aha moment. All of the components are using the same function definition, the point of which is to fire *once* after the period is over.

Comment: For what it's worth, `computed`s work the same way: if you put `debounce` in the setter, it will be one debounce for all instances. This is a somewhat subtle unexpected behavior, but it should be rare if your code is DRY. In the example, we're making multiple copies of data; the debounce should probably be done in the parent and be passed as the prop.

Comment: Also FWIW, you *can* define `processData` in the `data` section, where it will be created once for each instance.

Comment: @RoyJ I expect anything (outside the data function) using a debounced will suffer the same issue. That's a great thought about the data function by the way; it really is a factory function in line with what you were thinking last night. It's non-intuitive, but I agree, it should solve the problem as well.

Comment: Thank you - now it works as I expected. I am using method two as it looks cleaner and adds fewer lines to the code.

Comment: You saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

another solution that works for me is using `$watch` api to add a watcher after the component is created then the debounce function will not be shared between components

```
created () {
  this.$watch(
    'foo',
    debounce(function bar() {
      // do something
    },
    {}
  )
}
```